# jquery active nav 3 levels

Tags: jquery, navigation

Having trouble (clearly) with active navigation script on
[this site](http://pilkertonrealtors.com/agents/andrew-terrell/about/)

I'm using a slight tweak of [css-tricks active nav script](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url/)...

Here's my code:

```
if (!$('body').hasClass('home')) {
    $('#main-nav li a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
} else {
    $('#main-nav li:first-child').addClass('active');
}
```

It's working fine on the main [agency site](http://www.pilkertonrealtors.com/buying/index.php) but when we get one level deeper to agent pages (first link above) it's assigning them all the active class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Would love to keep this as a js solution and not deal with body id's.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the href of your links - all of them are `/agents/andrew-terrell/...`
so when you go for

```
location.pathname.split("/")[1]
```

you get `andrew-terrell`, which selects every link you have in your menu. Perhaps you should check against entire `location.pathname` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using

```
$('#main-nav li a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]')
```

which returns "agents". Since all your links start with agents, all of your links are getting the active class.

The below code will work on your agent pages

```
$('#main-nav li a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
```